# Pandas dataframe rendered with bokeh shows no marks

Tags: pandas, bokeh

I am attempting to create a simple hbar() chart on two columns [project, bug_count].  Sample dataframe follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'project': ['project1', 'project2', 'project3', 'project4'],
                  'bug_count': [43683, 31647, 27494, 24845]})
```

When attempting to render any chart: scatter, circle, vbar etc... I get a blank chart.

This very simple code snippet shows an empty viz. This example shows a `f.circle()` just for demonstration, I'm actually trying to implement a `f.hbar()`.

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure

f = figure()
f.circle(df['project'], df['bug_count'],size = 10)
show(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of `df['project']` are strings, i.e. categorical values, not numbers. Categorical ranges must be explicitly provided, since you are the only person who possess the knowledge of what order the arbitrary factors should appear in on the axis. Something like

```
p = figure(x_range=sorted(set(df['project'])))
```

There is an entire chapter in the User's Guide devoted to [Handling Categorical Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html), with many complete examples (including many bar charts) that you can refer to.

Comment: Very helpful, and I've finally made progress - even using ColumnDataSource.  However, bokeh is flipping the data source - the data source is already sorted based on bug_count, highest to lowest.  However, bokeh is flipping it such that the viz shows top down lowest to highest.  Using ColumnDataSource, this is my hbar() line `p.hbar(y='project', right='bug_count', source=source, height=0.9, color='red')`

Comment: Solved with this `p = figure(y_range=list(reversed(df['project'])))`

Comment: The factors show up on the axis in exactly the order you provide them (that is the main point: you are the only person who knows what the "right" order is)

Comment: That's the odd thing, I actually do a `groupby(['project'])['bug_count'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_indesx(name='bug_count')` earlier in the program and everthing is stored in new dataframe in the right order; seaborn even returns the data in the right order. Some how the order is reversing in one of these steps which is why `reversed()` worked.

Comment: There is no "right" order because it is an arbitrary decision which side to start from.  There is just the origin the tool stipulates, whatever that is. On a standard y-axis Bokeh starts from a lower-left origin, that means the first element of the factors list is at the bottom. But there is not any a-priori reason that Bokeh's order and Seaborn's conventions have to agree with one another.